# PayPal - Pass Customer ID from my website - Receive confirmation with same Customer ID from my website

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am working on a software service and am offering a monthly subscription for my software service.

I am currently working on the subscription part - and am wanting to implement a paypal monthly recurring payment solution.

I have spent quite a bit of time looking over PayPal documentation, and trying different buttons, webhooks, IPN methods etc.

The problem is that I am not sure what solution to use - **because I am confused by the multiple options.**

What is most important to me is - that when the customers fill out the form on my website - and are then directed PayPal to pay - I then want to know that specific Customer ID from my website has successfully paid.

I would like to know:

- Which SPECIFIC option(s) PayPal has that I can pass Customer ID from my website of that customer - let's say a subscription ID from my site - and that PayPal will then send the customer back with my subscription ID, that I passed them on to PayPal with.
  Which is the easiest option to do that with?

I simply want the customer to:

- sign up at my site. (my part)
- be issued a unique Customer ID from my website (my part)
- click a PayPal payment/subscribe button (my part)
- be sent to PayPal to pay for the subscription (paypal's part)
- be returned to my site with the unique Customer ID from my website from my site - as well as a confirmation of payment from PayPal (paypal's part)

Please do not simply pass me to the general area of the development sections -
As I said - I have already been through all of that and find there is **too much information**.

Please direct me to a specific solution, or example, or tutorial that covers a solution that will fit what I need.

Comment: The answer will depend on exactly which APIs you are using.  Are you working with the Classic API (NVP/SOAP) or the new REST API?

Comment: I have access to all areas of PayPal and am interested in any solutions that work as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Express Checkout API with Recurring Payments.

The best thing to do would be to create a local invoice record in your system, and then have a related customer ID associated with that invoice.

In the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request to PayPal you can include a PROFILEREFERENCE parameter, which would be the invoice ID you generated for that order in your system.  Then all future payments related to that profile would include this same reference ID as part of its data, so if you're using IPN, for example, it would be included there.

When working with Express Checkout the user is always guaranteed to end up back on your site to finish the checkout flow, so you can simply save data in sessions during checkout and update things like your database, email receipts, etc. directly in your payment flow.  Then you could use IPN to process the recurring payments after that, and again, it would include that same reference ID.  In IPN this would come back as `rp_invoice_id`.

Comment: Thanks :)
Is here a way to use Express Checkout API for subscription?
So something like:
payment: {
                                        transactions: [
                                            {
                                                amount: { total: '0.11', currency: 'USD' },
paypals_subscriptipn_id: 'like_you_can_with_html_button'
}
                                        ]

Like you can with their HTML buttons? Simply referencing the subscription as setup in my paypal account settings? If not? how do I use the Express Checkout API button for selling subscription?

Comment: What I explained above is a subscription (recurring payments profile).  So not really sure what you're asking here..??

Comment: Yes - I see that, and thank you.
I guess I'm just asking you an additional question about the express checkout button. Since you are the only one who responded to this question. If there was just a way to add a few parameters to the basic HTML javascript - it to have it process as a recurring billing subscription.

Comment: Express Checkout is API based.  There is no way to just add parameters to HTML.  It has to be built as an HTTP request to PayPal's API endpoints.